# Decompression failed after reading chunk of data from .gz compressed file stored in S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-s3, gzip

My application needs to read the huge compressed (.gz) file from S3 bucket. Every time we need to read smaller portion of data by giving startPos byte and endPos byte.

`def read_chunks(bucketname, key, startPos, endPos):
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

```
start_time = time.time()
response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucketname, Key=key, Range="bytes=%d-%d" % (startPos, endPos))
response1 = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucketname, Key=key, Range="bytes=%d-%d" % (startPos, endPos))
print (response['ContentLength'])
print ('\n')
n = response['Body'].read()
print (n)
decompressed = gzip.decompress(n)
print(decompressed)
```

`

I am getting the below error

`Traceback (most recent call last):   File "aws_s3_file.py", line 106, in <module>     read_chunks(bucketname, key, startPos, endPos)   File "aws_s3_file.py", line 73, in read_chunks     decompressed = gzip.decompress(n)   File "/opt/pym32/lib/python3.8/gzip.py", line 551, in decompress     return f.read()   File "/opt/pym32/lib/python3.8/gzip.py", line 292, in read     return self._buffer.read(size)   File "/opt/pym32/lib/python3.8/gzip.py", line 479, in read     if not self._read_gzip_header():   File "/opt/pym32/lib/python3.8/gzip.py", line 427, in _read_gzip_header     raise BadGzipFile('Not a gzipped file (%r)' % magic) gzip.BadGzipFile: Not a gzipped file (b'\x0b\x8d')`

How to decompress the smaller portion of data? Please note that the input file is .gz file only. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I need to get the smaller portion of data from .gz file from S3 bucket and decompress it.

I have tried adding header manually (sample header: b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00@\xdc8b\x02\xff. Please ignore the mtime bytes). But I ended up with another error. "Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached".

Comment: You simply cannot (reliably) take a chunk out of a compressed archive and decompress it. It's only consistent in its entirety. Try reading the entire file and decompress it to make sure it's not corrupt

Comment: Gzip is designed to be read from the beginning. You can't simply read a part in the middle and decompress it. With some tricks it might be possible to extract a block, but how to know where it starts without knowing the data before?